# Warning: Embedded web apps are still subject to access permissions

Tags: google-apps-script

As title says...
BUT, I've made a web app for output some result based on a data search using parameters submitted in a google form in my google site.
I work in a school so no way that all teachers has, or want to use, or want to waste time just for know which labs are available in some time slots.
I really need that everyone can run web app ... obviously I deployed it with access anyone, even anonimous but

https://sites.google.com/itsluigicasale.gov.it/prenotazionilab/trova-un-laboratorio-libero

have I made some errors? 
is there any workaround?

I'd like to use it without access or ask for permission for the users

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) and [mcve]. [Google Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Comment: Your web app works fine, what is the issue with it?

Comment: @ jescanellas It ask for an account and not all user of my organizzation has one.
(or want to use)... :(
It worked for you? didn't ask an account in @itsluigicasale.edu.it?

Comment: I haven't tried to submit the form, but if you do, you need a Google account to use it.